# MultiTouching different objects in android

Tags: android, object, multi-touch

Here is the scenario: I've wrote a fairly complex application that has joypad-like components on screen, an arbitrary number of them. When i developed this i was working with an Huawei phone that didn't support multitouch. As i began to realize the multitouch feature changes things in the way that the MotionEvent associated with a SINGLE object, flags an ACTION_POINTER_XXX action when 'multitouched'. Can someone point be the best way to reuse the gorgeous code that i already have? (every component independently implements the onTouch() method) =D

Thanks in advance,
JQCorreia

Comment: Are you looking to join the multiple independent onTouchListener's into one onTouchListener through multi-touch, or are you looking to use multi-touch within your multiple listeners?

Comment: Looking to multitouch independent multiple listeners. i.e the analog pads in a playstation gamepad.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-3-understanding-touch-events/1775) has a really good example of how to do multi-touch, including "pinching".  It's worked well for me.  Since you have already done touch handling the main difference with multi-touch is the "ACTION_POINTER" events that you have already pointed out, when the multiple fingers go "down" or "up".  The other difference is that motion events give the current location of all the fingers, rather than just one.

Comment: Not quite what i had in mind, i just want to touch 2 buttons and they independently respond. if i touch button 1 go forward if button 2 go left and be able to do those 2 things simultaneuosly. Sorry for the informal english i'm quite tired... =P

Comment: Aren't your multiple independent onTouchListeners already doing that for you?

Comment: Nope, because just an MotionEvent is released system wide during multitouch event so... There can be only one component touched.